# How to check with linq to sql that all users of a group have a user role?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, linq-to-sql, dao

I want to write a DAO method that checks if all users of a group have a specific user role and return either false or true.

I use NHibernate ad LINQ.

This is what I have done so far:

```
public bool AllByGroupHaveUserRole(Group group, UserRole userRole)
{
    if (group == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("group");
    }

    if (userRole == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("userRole");
    }

    var groups = HibernateTemplate.Execute(session => (from user in session.Query<User>()
                                                       where user.Group == @group
                                                       group user by user.UserRole.Id into groupedUsers
                                                       select new { groupedUsers.Key })).ToList();

    return groups.Count < 2 && groups.All(o => o.Key == userRole.Id);
}
```

Right now, I am executing the query in the DB and later I check for the UserRole in memory.

Is it possible to do it all in one NHibernate query and just return the result?

If there are no users in a group with a specific user role the method should also return true.

This is also how the LINQ method IEnumerable.All method works.

```
Return Value: True if every element of the source sequence passes the test in the specified predicate, or if the sequence is empty; otherwise, False.
```

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did't test the code

```
from user in session.Query<User>()
                      where user.Group == @group
                      group user by new { RoleId = user.UserRole.Id } into groupedUsers
                      select groupedUsers.Select(t => t.UserRole.Id).Distinct().Count() < 2 || groupedUsers.Where(t => t.UserRole == userRole).Any()
```